# How do I get a function to repeat itself [x] many times?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a dice rolling program.

Everything has worked so far until I got to this

Code so far:

```
function randomNum(max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - 1 + 1)) + 1;
}

var names = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten', 'eleven', 'twelve', 'thirteen', 'fourteen', 'fifteen', 'sixteen', 'seventeen', 'eighteen', 'nineteen', 'twenty'];

function rollDice(number, sides) {
    return("Rolled "+ names[number] +" "+ names[sides] +" sided dice");
}

function randomDice(number, sides) {
    function repeat(number) {
        randomNum(sides);
        if(sides > 20) sides==20;
}}
```

The problematic bit is this:

```
function randomDice(number, sides) {
    function repeat(number) {
        randomNum(sides);
        if(sides > 20) sides==20;
}}
```

What I want is to say something like

```
randomDice(2, 20)
```

which should roll 2 twenty sided dice, but I can't get my randomNum function to repeat itself two times if I want it to roll multiple times.

EDIT: The problem has been answered, thank you everybody for helping :)

Comment: Why not just loop and collect the roll results?

Comment: You're not even calling the repeat function :) You could do a loop as guys suggested or play around with recursion just for fun.

Comment: Simply change out your `function repeat(number)` declaration to a for-loop: `for( var n = 0; n < number; n++)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change out your `function repeat(number)` declaration to a for-loop: `for( var n = 0; n < number; n++)`. This will get the repetition you desire:

```js
function randomNum(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + 1;  // No reason to do max+1-1
}

var names = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten', 'eleven', 'twelve', 'thirteen', 'fourteen', 'fifteen', 'sixteen', 'seventeen', 'eighteen', 'nineteen', 'twenty'];

function rollDice(number, sides) {
  return "Rolled " + names[number] + " " + names[sides] + " sided dice";
}

function randomDice(number, sides) {
  var results = []  // Create array to store results
  if (sides > 20)  // Limit sides, but only needs to be done once (outside loop)
    sides == 20;
  for (var n = 0; n < number; n++) {
    var name = names[randomNum(sides)]; // Translate the number to a word
    results.push(name);    // Add the word to the array
  }
  console.log(rollDice(number, sides)); // Display the context
  return results; // Return the results as an array
}

console.log(randomDice(2, 20).join(', '));  // Display the values chosen as comma-separated values
```

I added a few more things, assuming this is the type of implementation you are looking for. Please adjust as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Try a for loop

```
for (i=0; i<2; i++){
   repeat(20);
}
//move this function out of the randomDice function
function repeat(number) {
    randomNum(sides);
    if(sides > 20) sides==20;
}
```

Comment: IMO it doesn't make any sense to duplicate `randomNum` inside a wrongly-named `repeat` function. Clamping the max number of sides makes it *somewhat* reasonable, but `repeat` doesn't... repeat, so probably should be called something else, at the very least.

Answer (score -6):

You want the `setInterval` method: [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)

Comment: o-o-o-o-o-overkill

Comment: you should be more explicit in your answer, and I don't think is what he means.

Comment: That seems a bit unwieldy just to roll a die *n* times, no?

Comment: `setInterval` will repeat a function *over time*, whereas OP wants to do that *immediately*. Setting the interval to `0` or other low number will put all the repeat calls on the event loop which is harder to work with.